# trying to install xlrd in specific directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, xlrd

I'm trying to pip install install xlrd to my local directory. First, I opened the anaconda prompt and tried this

```
pip install xlrd
```

No problems there. Then I try this

```
pip install xlrd -t <my windows path>
```

But it spits out an error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Code (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Code
```

What's the issue here and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this may seem like a stupid answer but it might help some people. My windows path had folder names with spaces. I removed them and it works.